# Implementing Huffman class into another class

Tags: java

I almost have a working Huffman algorithm but I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement it / or make it work together with the Code class. It is my method generateHuffmanCode that needs to be working with the Code class.
I don't know if I'm missing something or if I'm just using the wrong approach.

My Huffman class

```
package code;
  
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
  
import code.Code;
import application.TCode;
  
  
class Node{
    Character ch;
    Integer freq;
    Node left = null, right = null;
      
    Node(Character ch, Integer freq){
        this.ch = ch;
        this.freq = freq;
    }
      
    public Node (Character ch, Integer freq, Node left, Node right) {
        this.ch = ch;
        this.freq = freq;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
      
      
}
  
public class Huffman {
      
    public static void encode(Node root, String str, Map<Character, String> huffmanCode) {
        if (root == null) {
            return;
        }
        if(isLeaf(root)) {
            huffmanCode.put(root.ch, str.length() > 0 ? str : "1");
        }
        encode(root.left, str + '0', huffmanCode);
        encode(root.right, str + '1', huffmanCode);
    }
      
          
      
    public static int decode(Node root, int index, StringBuilder sb) {
        if(root == null) {
            return index;
        }
        index++;
          
        if(isLeaf(root)) {
            System.out.println(root.ch);
        }
        index++;
          
        root = (sb.charAt(index) == '0') ? root.left : root.right;
        index = decode(root, index, sb);
        return index;
    }
      
    public static boolean isLeaf(Node root) {
        return root.left == null && root.right == null;
    }
      
      
    public static void generateHuffmanCode(Code c) {
//      if(c == null || c.length() == 0) {
//          return;
//      }
        Map<Character, double> freq = new HashMap<>();   // why can't I use a double in Map<Character, double>??
        for(char s : probability.toCharArry()){
            freq.put(s, freq.getOrDefault(s, 0) + 1);
        }
          
        PriorityQueue<Node> pq;
        pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(l -> l.freq));
          
        for(var entry: freq.entrySet()) {
            pq.add(new Node(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
        }
          
        while (pq.size() != 1) {
            Node left = pq.poll();
            Node right = pq.poll();
              
              
            int sum = left.freq + right.freq;
            pq.add(new Node(null, sum, left, right));
        }
          
        Node root = pq.peek();
          
        Map<Character, String> huffmanCode = new HashMap<>();
        encode(root, "", huffmanCode);
          
        System.out.println("Huffman Codes are: " + huffmanCode);
        System.out.println(probability);
          
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(char s : probability.toCharArray()) {
            sb.append(huffmanCode.get(s));
        }
        System.out.println("The endcoded String is: " + sb);
        System.out.println("The decoded String is: " );
          
        if (isLeaf(root)) {
            while (root.freq-- > 0) {
                System.out.println(root.ch);
            }
        } else {
            int index = -1;
            while(index < sb.length() - 1) {
                index = decode(root, index, sb);
            }
        }
    }
      
  
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          
  
        generateHuffmanCode(Code probability);
          
//      Code.CodeItem[] ci = {
//              new Code.CodeItem("A", 0.12),
//              new Code.CodeItem("B", 0.19),
//              new Code.CodeItem("C", 0.40),
//              new Code.CodeItem("D", 0.13),
//              new Code.CodeItem("E", 0.16)                
//      };
//      Code c = new Code(ci);
          
          
    }
  
  
}
```

And my Code class

```
package code;
 
public final class Code {
 
    private CodeItem[] item = null;
     
    public final static class CodeItem {
 
        private String symbol;
        private double probability;  // the sum of all probabilities must be approx. 1
        private String encoding;     // a string containing only '0' and '1'
         
        public CodeItem(String symbol, double probability, String encoding) {
            this.symbol = symbol.trim();
            this.probability = probability;
            this.encoding = encoding;
            if (!is01() || this.symbol == null || this.symbol.length() == 0 || this.probability < 0.0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
         
        public CodeItem(String symbol, double probability) {
            this(symbol, probability, null);
        }
         
        public String getSymbol() {
            return symbol;
        }
 
        public double getProbability() {
            return probability;
        }
 
        public String getEncoding() {
            return encoding;
        }
 
        public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
            this.encoding = encoding;
        }
 
        public boolean is01() {
             
            if (encoding == null || encoding.length() == 0)
                return true;
             
            for (int i = 0; i < encoding.length(); ++i)
                if ("01".indexOf(encoding.charAt(i)) < 0)
                    return false;
             
            return true;
        }
         
    }
     
    public Code(CodeItem[] codeItem) {
 
        if (codeItem == null || codeItem.length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
 
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < codeItem.length; ++i) {
            sum += codeItem[i].probability;
            if (codeItem[i].probability == 0.0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (Math.abs(sum - 1.0) > 1e-10) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
             
        item = new CodeItem[codeItem.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < codeItem.length; ++i)
            item[i] = codeItem[i];
         
    }
     
    public boolean is01() {
         
        for (int i = 0; i < item.length; ++i)
        if (!item[i].is01())
            return false;
         
        return true;
    }
 
     
    public double entropy() {
         
        double result = 0.0;
         
        for(int i = 0; i < item.length; ++i)
            result += item[i].probability * (-Math.log(item[i].probability) / Math.log(2.0));       
         
        return result;
    }
     
    public double averageWordLength() {
         
        double result = 0.0;
         
        for(int i = 0; i < item.length; ++i)
            result += item[i].encoding.length() * item[i].probability;      
         
        return result;
    }
     
    public boolean isPrefixCode() {
         
        for(int i = 1; i < item.length; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                if (item[i].encoding.startsWith(item[j].encoding) || item[j].encoding.startsWith(item[i].encoding))
                    return false;
        return true;
    }
     
    public int size() {
        return item.length;
    }
     
    public CodeItem getAt(int index) {
        return item[index];
    }
     
    public CodeItem getBySymbol(String symbol) {
 
        for (int i = 0; i < item.length; ++i) {
            if (item[i].symbol.equals(symbol))
                    return item[i];
        }
        return null;
    }
     
         
    public String toString() {
         
        String result = "";
         
        for(int i = 0; i < item.length; ++i) {
            result += item[i].symbol + " (" + item[i].probability +  ") ---> " + item[i].encoding + "\n";
        }
         
        return result.substring(0, result.length()-1);
    }
     
 
}
```

Comment: *`// why can't I use a double in Map<Character, double>??`* Because a `Map` is a key-value collection of objects. A `double` is not an object

Comment: `Double` is an object.